# How does the first level ability of the Fiend warlock work?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, hit-points

What exactly do the words mean in the 1st level Fiend warlock subclass feature?

> #### Dark One’s Blessing
>
> Starting at 1st level, when you reduce a hostile creature to 0 hit points, you gain temporary hit points equal to your Charisma modifier + your warlock level (minimum of 1).

And if I do more damage and my damage is greater than 0, does that work? How does this even work?

Comment: Which edition of D&D are you playing, and what is the source for this feature? I’m not familiar with a Fiend Sorcerer, but it may be from an edition I’ve never played.

Comment: This may be a result of machine translation, but I suspect this is asking about 5e's Fiend Warlock, which has a 1st level feature "Dark One's Blessing" with identical rules text (bar class name obviously). I've closed it pending that confirmation, or a different clarification, at which point it may be reopened.

Comment: I translate through a translator.
Yes, Someone_Evil is right. It is an ability. 
The question is, if the enemy's health drops below 0, not exactly 0, then it works. Yeah 5e. Sorry first time using this site and not yet a native speaker

Comment: No worries, we might just occasionally have to work a bit harder to understand each-other. I've fixed some of the info in the question based on those comments and reopened as the question now seems completely clear to me.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for the inconvenience. Couldn't find the answer anywhere, thought I'd have to go overseas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The minimum hit points is 0, and the feature tells you how many temporary hit points you get.

First, the minimum hit points is 0, there is no such thing as negative hit points:

> A creature’s current hit points (usually just called hit points) can be any number from the creature’s hit point maximum down to 0.

So when you deal damage and reduce a creature’s hit points to 0, you gain temporary hit points equal to:

> your Charisma modifier + your warlock level (minimum of 1).